# computed includes doesn't work in Vue.js. How it fix?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to use "includes" in Vue with my v-model and  Vue.js log error, but if i write (.includes("blabla)) -> it all good.

What is problem?

and how return all array if (if) will work?

like this.emojiesByCategory.push() ?

please help

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="emoji_picker">
            <div class="picker_container">
                <input v-model="search">
                <div class="category"
                     v-for="category in categories"
                     :key="`category_${category}`"
                >
                    <span>{{ category }}</span>
                    <div class="emojis_container">
                        <button
                            v-for="(emoji, index) in category_emojis(category)" // ERROR HERE
                            :key="`emoji_${index}`"
                        >
                            {{ emoji }}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import data from '../data.json'

export default {
    name: 'App',
    data() {
        return {
            search: "",
            emojiesByCategory: ""
        }
    },
    computed: {
        categories() {
            return Object.keys(data);
        },

        category_emojis: () => (category) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(data[category]).length; i++) {
                if (Object.keys(data[category])[i].includes(this.search)) { // ERROR THERE !!!
                    console.log(Object.values(data[category])[i]) 
            }
            return Object.values(data[category])
        }
    },
}
</script>



// how fix  this?
```

My json look like:

```
{
    "Frequently used": {
        "confused": "",
        "neutral_face": "",
        "blush": "",
        "heart_eyes": ""
    },
    // and others
}
```

please help me

Comment: Please at least give us the error you get.

Comment: are all properties in `data.category` Arrays? `Object.keys(data[category])[i].includes` would require that - since your "json" has no Arrays, I believe you may not know what you are doing

Comment: And if you don't know, then ask.. as they've done. As the previous comment says you're trying to find an array item, when your json doesn't contain an array (specifically the `[i]` part which is trying to access a member of an array from its index). I'd recommend reading about arrays here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With using arrow function in the computed property, you will lose access to `this.search`. When you use `this.search` inside your arrow function, it's not referring to your Vue instance's data property search, but to this in the parent scope (which might be `window` in the browser), where search is probably `undefined`.

So, using simple definition:

```
category_emojis() {
    return (category) => {
        let filteredEmojis = {};

        for (let emoji in data[category]) {
            if (emoji.includes(this.search)) {
                filteredEmojis[emoji] = data[category][emoji];
            }
        }

        return Object.values(filteredEmojis);
    }
}
```

Also, note that you initially initialized `emojiesByCategory` as a `string` in your `data`. change that to an `array` too.

Comment: thank yoy very match!